# Observable.timer delays the second call more than expected

Tags: angular, angular5, observable

I am trying to show rows of a large dataset "smoothly" by adding 20 rows every 1 second. I am using Observable.timer but it behaves strangely.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.showMoreRows();
  }

  public showMoreRows() {

    console.log("first");

    Observable.timer(1000, 1000)
      .subscribe(i => {
        if (this.limit < this.totalCount) {
          console.log("next: " + i);
          this.limit += 20;
        }
      });
  }
```

I get the following result in the console.
As you can see, the second call is being called 1 minute after the first one. Why does that happen and how can I prevent it from happening?

[image: Console Results]

Comment: Can't reproduce -> [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-l72qv1)

Comment: As  I said, I have a large dataset loaded before. If I don't do this trick, html freezes.